# How to upcast this object without splicing, based on a condition?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm stumbling upon a probably trivial issue. I want to call `doSomething()` on an instance of `AbstractParser`, where said instance is of a derived class `FooParser` or `BarParser`. Whether it is one or the other depends on the runtime arguments supplied by the user. The remainder of the code should only have a way to access the parent `AbstractParser` object. See below.

```
AbstractParser& myParser;   // Error: can't have a reference to nothing
if(some_condition){
    FooParser parser = FooParser();
    myParser = parser;
}else{
    BarParser parser = BarParser();
    myParser = parser;
}
// lots of code with other things ...
parser.doSomething();
```

Based on a condition, I want to use `myParser` (or a pointer to it) outside the scope of the `if` block, and `myParser` should behave as the appropriate derived object. I want to avoid copying my object, and (if possible) the move constructor. Without the condition, I could do this

```
FooParser parser = FooParser();
AbstractParser &myParser = parser;     // upcast without slicing
// lots of code with other things ...
parser.doSomething();
```

And it would be clean and elegant, upcasting without slicing the `parser`. I'm not sure how to do this now.

**How can I upcast my derived parsers without copying the objects created or having them go out of scope?** Do I need to create an `std::unique_ptr<AbstractClass>` and use `make_unique<FooParser>()` inside the `if`? Or should I use a function that returns a reference to the derived class? Or a `static_cast<AbstractClass>`? Or am I overcomplicating this?

Comment: This is typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You are asking to fix your solution without explaining (with enough details) what this code supposed to do. Use of `std::unique_ptr<AbstractClass>` probably is a good solution, but there might be better approaches to your problem.

Comment: @MarekR I thought I was clear, but I've re-edited. I want to create an object inside the `if` block, and keep a way of accessing its parent interface outside the `if` scope. I want this to be performant, as copying is heavy in this object

Comment: The key word in the question is "pointer". You already know what to do, just not realize it. Instead of a reference, use a pointer, and the shown code will mostly work, as is. Make it a unique_ptr, and construct it with `new`. The End.

Comment: if you can get `some_condition` to evaluate at compiler time, you can use condition templates to get your result.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos Since we are in C++17 one can even use `if constexpr` which is much more comfortable. But I would say that is a pretty big if.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos Not possible, it is dependent on runtime arguments

Comment: @BlueMoon93 you did some edit, but it looks like you've missed the point of XY problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy solution is to use a `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<AbstractParser> myParser;
if (some_condition)
    myParser = std::make_unique<FooParser>();
else
    myParser = std::make_unique<BarParser>();

myParser->doSomething();
```

If you want to avoid the heap allocation, you have to use something like `std::variant`, but it's not as convenient:

```
std::variant<std::monostate, FooParser, BarParser> var;
AbstractParser *myParser;
if (x)
    myParser = &var.emplace<FooParser>();
else
    myParser = &var.emplace<BarParser>();

myParser->doSomething();
```

Comment: You can certainly use `std::variant`, then `std::visit` to get a plain ref out of it, and we're back exactly where we were. More complicated, but nobody ever accused C++ of being easy.

Comment: Because the `parser` is now allocated to the heap? I will have to research what is `std::variant`

Comment: @BlueMoon93 What seems to be the problem with having the parser on the heap?

Comment: @TedLyngmo For this case, it is not a problem. I want to learn how to use it though, may be useful in the future

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Ok. Well, then you have the `variant` as HolyBlackCat showed above. I think you'll find very few situations when it's actually meaningful to spend time to force stuff on the stack. I've dealt with moving stuff _from_ the stack to not get a stack overflow more often.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```cpp
std::variant<std::monostate, FooParser, BarParser> parser;
if(some_condition) {
    parser = FooParser();
} else {
    parser = BarParser();
}

std::visit([](auto & p) {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<std::decay_t(decltype(p)), std::monostate>) { 
    } else { 
         p.doSomething();
    } 
} ,parser);
```

I think this might even elide the dynamic dispatch for the function call.

Comment: You are right. I added an `std::monostate` default type. Of course this makes the code much more complex.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is to extract code to separate methods:

```cpp
class Foo {

    void subAction(AbstractParser& parser) { 
        parser.doSomething();
    }
    void action(bool some_condition) {
        if (some_condition) {
            FooParser foo;
            subAction(foo);
        } else {
            BarParser bar;
            subAction(bar);
        }
    }
};
```

Note that no heap is involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract the usage of the parser to a function then call that. So from:

```cpp
AbstractParser& myParser;
if (condition()) {
    FooParser parser = FooParser();
    stuff_1();
    myParser = parser;
} else {
    BarParser parser = BarParser();
    stuff_2();
    myParser = parser;
}
stuff_3(myParser);
```

To:

```
([](auto&& use_parser){
    if (condition()) {
        FooParser parser = FooParser();
        stuff_1();
        use_parser(parser);
        return;
    } else {
        BarParser parser = BarParser();
        stuff_2();
        use_parser(parser);
        return;
    }
})([](AbstractParser& myParser) {
    stuff_3(myParser);
});
```

May be easier with a completely separate function (e.g., just `stuff_3` would work in this case, so you wouldn't need any lambdas), but the lambdas let you capture stuff so it doesn't need to be too heavily redesigned.